# I need to dynamically fit the height of the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to add the height of the iframe dynamically based on the content it has on the external URL using Javascript. But it is not working as expected and I could see some fixed height or excess space available in the screen.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="iframe-container iframe-container--" data-theme="drupal">
  <iframe class="iframe-container__inner" id="friendsgiving" src="https://cesar-canine-cuisine.campaign.playable.com/cesarfriendsgiving" title="Friendsgiving" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

```
var iframeContainerInnerList = document.querySelectorAll('.iframe-container__inner');
iframeContainerInnerList.forEach(iframeContainerInner => {
var html = iframeContainerInner.contentWindow.parent.document.documentElement;
iframeContainerInner.style.height = html.clientHeight + 'px';
});
```

This approach gives me the entire window height where I could see empty space in the screen as the content in the external URL is very less.

Second approach:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("friendsgiving");
var newheight;
var newwidth;
if(iframe) {
 newheight = iframe.contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
 newwidth = iframe.contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
}
iframe.height = (newheight) + "px";
iframe.width = (newwidth) + "px";
```

In this approach the parent height is set as 150px and the content's are getting hidden below

Can someone help me in finding the solution for defining the height of the parent div dynamically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JS lib to do this called [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer). If you want to roll your own then there are a whole host of ways to try and workout the content height of an iframe. On top of that different browsers can give marginally different answers and they can all be broken by CSS if you try hard enough.

In most cases `document.body.offsetHeight` offers the closest to the right answer. If that doesn’t work, either check your CSS, or loop over every element in the page to find which one has the lowest bottom edge.

Once your only a few pixels out, then the simplest solution is to just disable the scroll bars on the iframe.

Next if the content of the iframe is in anyway dynamic, you’ll need to detect changes and recalculate the size of your iframe. This can be done by a mixture of listening for every event that can cause content reflow and using the MutationObserver API to listen for changes in the DOM.

Finally your code does not appear to be waiting for the iframe to finish loading, which might be why your not getting the answer your expecting.

Comment: Was this helpful?